# How to find nth digit of an irrational number of the form $\sqrt(x)$

Tags: algorithm, matlab, numerical-analysis

I'm writing a matlab code which uses digits of an irrational number. I tried finding it using a taylor expansion of  $\sqrt(1+x)$. Since division to large numbers could be a bad idea for Matlab, this method seems to me not a good one.

I wonder if there is any simpler and efficient method to do this?

Comment: Please post some code and some examples, what's the input and the desired output. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the fast response . I need to use it in this form:  output= findNthDigit(x, n)  all of them will be integer.  function will consider the x as sqrt(x)  and return the nth digit of it as output.

Comment: I know that there is an algoritm for pi  (known as BBP) for example, but I need to have more options.

Comment: What values does `x` take? Integer? Rational?

Comment: x and n are both  integer here .  (x is a non-square integer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the Symbolic Toolbox, [`vpa`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) does that. You can specify the number of significant digits you want:

```
x = '2'; %// define x as a *string*. This avoids loss of precision
n = 100; %// desired number of *significant* digits
result = vpa(['sqrt(' x ')'], n);
```

The result is a [symbolic variable](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symbolic-variables-expressions-and-functions.html). If needed, convert to a string:

```
result = char(result);
```

In the example above,

```
result =
1.414213562373095048801688724209698078569671875376948073176679737990732478462107038850387534327641573
```

Note that this is subject to **rounding**. For example, the result with `n = 7` is `1.414214` instead of `1.414213`.

In **newer Matlab versions** (tested on R2017b), using a char input with `vpa` is discouraged, and support for this may be removed in the future. The recommended approach is to first define the variable as symbolic, and then apply the required operations to it:

```
x = sym(2);
n = 100;
result = vpa(sqrt(x), n);
```

Comment: although I said above that I need nth digit, this version also might be useful for me too. thanks, appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you need a method of [digit-by-digit root calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Digit-by-digit_calculation) that was discovered long before computer era.

Comment: thanks appreciated your response, I'll look into it, seems promising :)